# Stringizing argument of macro to be unicode

Tags: macros, c-preprocessor, string-literals, stringification

I'm trying to stringize the argument of a macro such that it will give unicode string i.e. I want to do get the following :

```
WIDEN(4>5)  L"4>5"
```

And my macro is this :

```
#define WIDEN(x) L #x
```

Unfortunately doesn't work. How to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use e.g. the pre-processors contatenating operator `##`:

```
#define WIDEN(x)  L ## #x
```